# Focus goes to upper field(text field) after setting the date box in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

[image]

I am implementing the a pop up screen .On pop up screen I have one text field and date box .actually on clicking the date box and setting the date the focus goes to upper text field actually i try on fiddle .The issue is created (i don't know why).
First go to intex.html click header button(+).This pop up screen open fill text data on that open date box add date it goes to above field..:(same code i write on fiddle but it is not reproduce this.

Here is that code
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip[image]
I also try like that but no effect..:( focus is goes to above field.:I need please look again this question

```
<div data-role="content">
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" >
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="mydate" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>
                        <!--input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h"  -->
                           <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" class="caseDate_h" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"zindex":1200}'/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="textarea-12" class="caseTextArea_h"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: can you post link to that fiddle you tried ?

Comment: i tried this there is no issue display on that. i will post

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravi1989/3yG9E/5/ ..No focus come above the field.

Comment: you can unfocus that field, $("#text-12").blur(); and focus something else $("#someId").focus();

Comment: i also try this .I will explain the problem again.actually when i open  the pop up after pressing (+) on header .Write something on text field  and go to date box enter date .After enter date it goes to above text field.But it is not going in fiddle

Comment: can you download my www folder and run index.html  then open press+ button , after that fill this it show this

Comment: please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Hi here is my fiddle here you can check on chrome that focus goes on upward field when date box select the date .After that it goes to text field.http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/uhdYv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case Name:

```
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="mydate" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>                       
                <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="textarea-12" class="caseTextArea_h"></textarea>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you please tell why it is occurring ?

Comment: can you solve my last question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699743/how-to-remove-the-current-date-from-date-box-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

Cannot access drop box, and the code is huge, but what i think might be a silly thing that the for="text-12" is being repeated, please attach the corresponding id with which the label is being associated for the date part.

Comment: explain more please this part "for="text-12"" I take this for all text field .what is the use of for ?

Comment: what i mean is label has tag "for" which indicates it a label for which input control. it is generally the name/id of the input control. to associate them together. so how can you use text-12 for all three controls.

Comment: so you mean i take all text-12 for three ?