# how to insert date picker in ios using phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Please help me in implementing the date picker in IOS .I try three things

1) Type ="Date " it is working fine but there is no done button.
2) I take date box there is  of focus and fluctuation.
Now i thought to insert Native plugin of date picker in iOS(Latest).
Or  provide some example of mobile scroll in IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Js code:

/**
 * Cordova DatePicker Plugin
 * Copyright (c) Greg Allen 2011
 * MIT Licensed
 *
 * Updated for Cordova 2.1 by Robert (Jamie) Munro
 */
if (typeof cordova !== "undefined") {
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function DatePicker() {
        this._callback;
    }

    /**
     * show - true to show the ad, false to hide the ad
     */
    DatePicker.prototype.show = function(options, cb) {
        var padDate = function(date) {
            if (date.length == 1) {
                return ("0" + date);
            }
            return date;
        };

        if (options.date) {
            options.date = options.date.getFullYear() + "-" +
            padDate(options.date.getMonth()+1) + "-" +
            padDate(options.date.getDate()) +
            "T" + padDate(options.date.getHours()) + ":" +
            padDate(options.date.getMinutes()) + ":00Z";
        }
        var defaults = {
            mode : 'datetime',
            date : '',
            allowOldDates : true,
            allowFutureDates : true
        };

        for (var key in defaults) {
            if (typeof options[key] !== "undefined")
                defaults[key] = options[key];
        }
        this._callback = cb;

        cordova.exec("DatePicker.show", defaults);
    };

    DatePicker.prototype._dateSelected = function(date) {
        var d = new Date(parseFloat(date) * 1000);
        if (this._callback)
            this._callback(d);
    }

    cordova.addConstructor(function() {
                           if (!window.plugins) {
                           window.plugins = {};
                           }
                           window.plugins.datePicker = new DatePicker();
                           });
};

datepicker.m code:

//  Phonegap DatePicker Plugin
//  Copyright (c) Greg Allen 2011
//  MIT Licensed
//
//  Additional refactoring by Sam de Freyssinet

#import "DatePicker.h"

@interface DatePicker (Private)

// Initialize the UIActionSheet with ID <UIActionSheetDelegate> delegate UIDatePicker datePicker (UISegmentedControl)closeButton
- (void)initActionSheet:(id <UIActionSheetDelegate>)delegateOrNil datePicker:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker closeButton:(UISegmentedControl *)closeButton;

// Creates the NSDateFormatter with NSString format and NSTimeZone timezone
- (NSDateFormatter *)createISODateFormatter:(NSString *)format timezone:(NSTimeZone *)timezone;

// Creates the UIDatePicker with NSMutableDictionary options
- (UIDatePicker *)createDatePicker:(CGRect)pickerFrame;

// Creates the UISegmentedControl with UIView parentView, NSString title, ID target and SEL action
- (UISegmentedControl *)createActionSheetCloseButton:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

// Configures the UIDatePicker with the NSMutableDictionary options
- (void)configureDatePicker:(NSMutableDictionary *)optionsOrNil;

@end

@implementation DatePicker

@synthesize datePickerSheet = _datePickerSheet;
@synthesize datePicker = _datePicker;
@synthesize isoDateFormatter = _isoDateFormatter;

#pragma mark - Public Methods

- (CDVPlugin *)initWithWebView:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{
    self = (DatePicker *)[super initWithWebView:theWebView];

    if (self)
    {
        UIDatePicker *userDatePicker = [self createDatePicker:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
        UISegmentedControl *datePickerCloseButton = [self createActionSheetCloseButton:@"Close" target:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:)];
        NSDateFormatter *isoTimeFormatter = [self createISODateFormatter:k_DATEPICKER_DATETIME_FORMAT timezone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

        self.datePicker = userDatePicker;
        self.isoDateFormatter = isoTimeFormatter;
        userDatePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;

        [self initActionSheet:self datePicker:userDatePicker closeButton:datePickerCloseButton];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)show:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
    if (isVisible) {
        return;
    }

    [self configureDatePicker:options];
    [self.datePickerSheet showInView:[[super webView] superview]];
    [self.datePickerSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

    isVisible = YES;
}

- (void)dismissActionSheet:(id)sender {
    [self.datePickerSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

- (void)onMemoryWarning
{
    // It could be better to close the datepicker before the system
    // clears memory. But in reality, other non-visible plugins should
    // be tidying themselves at this point. This could cause a fatal
    // at runtime.
    if (isVisible) {
        return;
    }

    [self release];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_datePicker release];
    [_datePickerSheet release];
    [_isoDateFormatter release];

    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate methods

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.datePicker._dateSelected(\"%i\");", (int)[self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSince1970]];
    [super writeJavascript:jsCallback];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    isVisible = NO;
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

- (void)initActionSheet:(id <UIActionSheetDelegate>)delegateOrNil datePicker:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker closeButton:(UISegmentedControl *)closeButton
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:delegateOrNil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    [actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    self.datePickerSheet = actionSheet;

    [actionSheet release];
}

- (UIDatePicker *)createDatePicker:(CGRect)pickerFrame
{
    UIDatePicker *datePickerControl = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    datePickerControl.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
    return [datePickerControl autorelease];
}

- (NSDateFormatter *)createISODateFormatter:(NSString *)format timezone:(NSTimeZone *)timezone;
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timezone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];

    return [dateFormatter autorelease];
}

- (UISegmentedControl *)createActionSheetCloseButton:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:title]];

    closeButton.momentary = YES;
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [closeButton addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    return [closeButton autorelease];
}

- (void)configureDatePicker:(NSMutableDictionary *)optionsOrNil;
{
    NSString *mode = [optionsOrNil objectForKey:@"mode"];
    NSString *dateString = [optionsOrNil objectForKey:@"date"];
    BOOL allowOldDates = NO;
    BOOL allowFutureDates = YES;

    if ([[optionsOrNil objectForKey:@"allowOldDates"] intValue] == 1) {
        allowOldDates = YES;
    }

    if ( ! allowOldDates) {
        self.datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
    }

    if ([[optionsOrNil objectForKey:@"allowFutureDates"] intValue] == 0) {
        allowFutureDates = NO;
    }

    if ( ! allowFutureDates) {
        self.datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
    }

    self.datePicker.date = [self.isoDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    if ([mode isEqualToString:@"date"]) {
        self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    }
    else if ([mode isEqualToString:@"time"])
    {
        self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
    }
    else
    {
        self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    }
}

@end

Datepicker.h code:

//  Phonegap DatePicker Plugin
//  Copyright (c) Greg Allen 2011
//  MIT Licensed

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>


#ifndef k_DATEPICKER_DATETIME_FORMAT
#define k_DATEPICKER_DATETIME_FORMAT @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
#endif

@interface DatePicker : CDVPlugin <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    UIActionSheet *_datePickerSheet;
    UIDatePicker *_datePicker;
    NSDateFormatter *_isoDateFormatter;
    BOOL isVisible;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet* datePickerSheet;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDatePicker* datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDateFormatter* isoDateFormatter;


//- (void) prepare:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
- (void) show:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

Comment: can you please help me in this issue..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682114/why-focus-move-to-above-field-while-open-to-pop-up-in-jquery

Comment: here is the detail of that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665510/focus-goes-to-upper-fieldtext-field-after-setting-the-date-box-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

If you want native date picker use plug in:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/DatePicker

else use normal jquerymobile datebox:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/

Comment: you can change it to make it work in 2.7.0 we used it as it in 2.2.0

Comment: you used this date picker ? above link .it is o.9 phonegap ..:(