# How to remove the current date from date box in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to remove the current date from the date box .Actually when i open the date box it high light the current date.But user select date example "14".
If user again open date box it hightlight "14"and current date.
Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/uhdYv/1/

```
 <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" class="documentDate_h"  data-options='{"mode": "calbox","useNewStyle":true,"zindex":1200}' />
```

first click (+) button  on header .It show pop up .open date box .it show today date select any date .then again open date box.it show selected date and today's date.?

second issue how to change colour of monday , tuesday ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    For changing color of the current date from its default theme "a" you can use this:

     <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useNewStyle":true, "themeDateToday": "e", "zindex":2000}'/>

    Hence current date will be in yellow, instead of blue and choosen date can be default blue.

    refer these sites for theming of the call box:

    http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/fullopt.html
    http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/themes.html

There is no such setting for month text, so for "Tu We" etc override the class as per below:

.ui-datebox-griddate-label {
height: 15px!important;
line-height: 15px!important;
color: green;
}
```

To remove the highlighting of current date and only keep the selected date being highlighted you can do this:

But keeping both you would need to modify the datebox's api code itself...

Comment: Actually my question is different ..!! Actually today's date is selected when user click the another button

Comment: generally today's date is highlighted you do not want this feature? kindly please be clear on the requirements...

Comment: But if you see that in my fiddle the 17 is selected when user select another date .How to remove that..?

Comment: i will explain more..Actually today's date is highlighted .It fine for first time.But if user click for another date(select another)date then it close the date box.But if user again open the date box then highlghted date should be last selected not today's +previous selected..

Comment: If you get time please help me in these question .Actually i am begineer that why i am asking more question sorry for that .. also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706467/sqlite-query-not-working-while-checking-table-exist-or-not-in-sqlite-and-phone-g? noredirect =1#comment25803503_17706467

Comment: sorry i don not think there is an option to remove the current date..will look into it if i get time...meanwhile if someone can help it would be great..would need to catch the event which sets the date and here you can remove the current dates class..but not sure...

Comment: hmm..ok .If you have time please look this issue also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706467/sqlite-query-not-working-while-checking-table-exist-or-not-in-sqlite-and-phone-g?noredirect=1#comment25803503_17706467

Comment: From the fullopt.html page - if you wish to not highlight "today", set "calHighToday":false.